# I am trying to use a code-fold command in my YAML, however it does not work

Tags: r

I wanted to hide my code in R studio using code-fold. code-fold creates a link that if the audience wants to look at the code it is an option, but otherwise the code is hidden

In my YAML

```yaml
title:
author:
format:
editor
execute:
   echo: false
execute:
   code-fold: true
```

This does not work. I do not know if you can put 2 execute commands in the YAML

Comment: Hiding code goes against the philosophy of open source. R is unlikely to have built such a feature into it API. Perhaps you want to use one of the proprietary clones.

Comment: Are you asking about code folding for HTML in Rmarkdown or Quarto?

Comment: In addition to input and out formats (qmd / rmd, HTML), please share your expectations on output when disabling `echo` and  enabling  `code-fold` at the same time,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a Quarto question, `code-fold` is not an execute but a format option. Not quite sure what the expected result is when applying both `echo: false` and `code-fold: true`, but what you'd get is an output with no code and no fold as shown with 2nd code block in the following example:

````yaml
---
format: 
  html: 
    code-fold: true
execute: 
  echo: true
---
Options from `YAML`, echo and folding enabled:
```{r}
message("YAML: code-fold: true; echo: true")
```

Block with options, sets `code-fold: true` and `echo: false`:
```{r}
#| code-fold: true
#| echo: false
message("code-block: code-fold: true;  echo: false")
```
````

renders as:
[image: rendered Quarto output]